# Using replace with $1 interprets "$1" as a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm using the following code to try to wrap a 3-letter month string like "Nov" or "Sep" with a `span` tag. However, the text that gets written to the DOM is literally `<span class="list-view-month">$1</span>`, where $1 is being interpreted literally, instead of as a backreference to the regex match.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

```
// Date wrap
$('.list-view .dates').each(function(){
    var $me = $(this);
    var oldHtml = $me.html();
    var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(/\b[A-Za-z]{3}\b/,'<span class="list-view-month">$1</span>');
    $me.html(newHtml);
});
```

Comment: Replace `$1` with `$&` if you need to use the whole match.

Comment: You don't have any capturing groups in your regex that `$1` could refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `/\b[A-Za-z]{3}\b/` regex has no unescaped round brackets, and you need to reference the whole match inside the `replace` method, you just need to use `$&` backreference.

```
var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(/\b[A-Za-z]{3}\b/,'<span class="list-view-month">$&</span>');
                                                                               ^^
```

See [`String#replace` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> **`$&`**    Inserts the matched substring.

Comment: BTW, you can shorten the regex a bit by using a `/i` modifier that enforces case-insensitive matching: `/\b[A-Z]{3}\b/i`.